# MVC2 Post using sub-classes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm building one page to edit various product types. Each product type has a view model (TentProductVM, BootProductVM) that inherits from ProductVM. My MVC2 View checks the model type and adds fields as appropriate. For example, if the model is of type BootProductVM I call Html.TextBoxFor to add a field for the boot's foot size. Page displays fine.

The problem is the post. I've declared a function (in VB) as follows:

```
<HttpPost()>Function Edit(byval prod as ProductVM) As ActionResult
```

Of course, this function only receives the form data from the base class ProductVM. So instead I added a function for each product type:

```
<HttpPost()>Function EditTent(byval prod as TentProductVM) As ActionResult
<HttpPost()>Function EditBoot(byval prod as BootProductVM) As ActionResult
```

and point the View to the appropriate post function:

```
Using Html.BeginForm("Edit" & Model.ObjectTypeName, "Catalog")
```

However, when EditTent or EditBoot gets called, the prod parameter only contains data from the base class. All the fields declared in the subclass view models are left at default values.

What am I doing wrong? Or is there a better approach? (The obvious solution is multiple pages but, since ProductVM has many fields relative to the subclasses, I'd rather not.)

---

After much experimentation, I've decided not to use this approach. First, I couldn't get it to work without resorting to having an Action parameter of type FormCollection. Second, the obvious solution I discarded is appealing if I use a partial view. The partial view has all the fields associated with the base class (ProductVM), leaving only the fields associated with the derived classes (TentProductVM, BootProductVM) in the regular views.

Felt like I was fighting against the MVC auto-magic, which is never the right approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing to remember about MVC is that it's based on the "Convention over Configuration" mindset. So if you're passing a strongly typed class class instance to your action method, it expects it to be named "model".

Try changing your declarations to look like this:

```
<HttpPost()> Function EditTent(byval model as TentProductVM) As ActionResult
<HttpPost()> Function EditBoot(byval model as BootProductVM) As ActionResult
```

The other (less ideal) option would be to expect a FormCollection object in your action method.

```
<HttpPost()> Function EditTent(byval form as FormCollection) as ActionResult
```

**Update**

Just updating to include some of the discussion points below...  In order to post a strongly typed object to a controller action method, the types need to match up.

Assuming your controller's action method looks like this:

```
<HttpPost()> Function EditTent(byval model as ProductVM) As ActionResult
```

Your view should be typed accordingly:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Your.Namespace.ProductVM>" %>
```

Comment: To my surprise, I changed the parameter name to "model" and it is set to null!

Comment: Could the problem be that my view inherits _System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage(Of MyNamespace.ProductVM)_ but my post function parameter is of the subclass _BootProductVM_? (Which is of course unavoidable if editing various product type are to share one page.)

Comment: That'll do it. If you're going to have a shared view that uses a generic ViewModel like that, you're going to have to accept a "ProductVM" in your action method. You'd then map it to your actual data model inside your controller method. You could also create a custom ModelBinder, but I think the first option would be easiest.

Comment: Ah, how would I "map it to your actual data model"? If I accept parameter of type ProductVM in my action, how would MVC (or I) map the subclass fields to my parameter?

Comment: Well, assuming that your ProductVM is simply a ViewModel, and you've got an entity class that you're using to persist to information to a data store, you could write the mapping code by hand (e.g. - entity.Property1 = model.Property1... ) or use something like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) to help you automate it.

Comment: Sorry my question wasn't clear... How does my action method receive the form values if the model parameter is of type ProductVM? (BTW, thanks for you suggestions!)

Comment: MVC's default model binding functionality will try match up the ID attribute of each HTML form element with an equivalent property on the corresponding model class. Would you mind updating your question with more detailed code? An example model and view might help clarify exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: That's my point. If the Action's parameter is of the base class type (ProductVM) how can MVC match the form's fields with those in a derived class (BootProductVM)?!? I assume it cannot. In any case, I'm moving on to a cleaner solution that avoids this issue. Again, thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Probably. It would involve jumping though a lot of extra hoops, perhaps unnecessarily. Best of luck on your project.